# Not show any record in DataTable select method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

My code:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, "ali");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "reza");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "mehdi");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "alireza");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "amirali");

    var result = dt.Select("name like '%ali%'");
    GridView1.DataSource = result;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Problem:

```
   not show any record in GridView
```

Comment: Have you tried `var result = dt.Select("name like '*ali*'");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just set filter?

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter ="name like '%ali%'";
GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

or

```
var result = dt.Select("name like '%ali%'").CopyToDataTable();
```

In your case result is of `DataRow[]` may be that is the reason binding fails.

Answer (score 2):

Gridview is not showing any rows because select returns datarow array and you cannot bind datarow array to gridview.

you can try this

```
var result = dt.Select("name like '%ali%'");
GridView1.DataSource = result.Select(r => r.ItemArray[0]);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem still persists, You can try this code .

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Trial");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "ali");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "reza");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "mehdi");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "alireza");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "amirali");

            DataRow[] result = dt.Select("name like '*%ali%*'");
            DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
            dtnew.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dtnew.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            foreach (DataRow dr in result)
            {
                dtnew.ImportRow(dr);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = dtnew;    
            GridView1.DataBind();
```